# Put CSV Column Data into Div Class

Tags: php, arrays

I have this php script that creates multiple tables out of csv data. It works great, but I am unsure how to get the first column (League) into the div class so that I can append each one into a matching parent div with jquery.

```
<?php
$csv = "League,Team,Date,Opponent,Result
american,MIN,May 3,UTA,W
american,SAC,May 3,DAL,L
american,SAC,May 4,TOR,W
american,SAC,May 7,MIL,W
national,NYN,May 5,BAL,L
national,NYN,May 7,MIA,W
national,DET,May 6,DEN,L
national,DET,May 7,POR,L";

$csv_array = explode("\n", $csv);

$tables = [];
foreach($csv_array as $key => $value) {
    if ($key == 0) {
        continue;
    }
    $line = explode(',', $value);
    if (array_key_exists($line[1], $tables)) {
        $tables[$line[1]][] = $line;
    } else {
        $tables[$line[1]] = [$line];
    }
}

foreach ($tables as $key => $value) {
    echo "<div class=\"$line[0]\">";
    echo "<table><tr><th>$key</th></tr><tr>";
    foreach (explode(',', $csv_array[0]) as $keyHeader => $valueHeader) {
                if (in_array($keyHeader, [0, 1])) {
            continue;
        }
        echo "<th>$valueHeader</th>";
    }
    echo '</tr>';
    foreach ($value as $keyRow => $valueRow) {
        echo '<tr>';
            foreach ($valueRow as $keyValue => $valueValue) {
                if (in_array($keyValue, [0, 1])) {
                    continue;
                }
                echo "<td>$valueValue</td>";
            }
        echo '</tr>';
    }
    echo '</table></div>';
}
?>
```

I know that the data is in $line[0], but that's as much as I can figure out. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to really tell what's going on with your code line by line, so you might consider a better practice of commenting each step of the way to document what you're trying to achieve. This will mostly benefit you when trying to look at your own code later.

I couldn't really see a direct way to extract the corresponding League based on the way you constructed your iterators. The reason that `$line[0]` is always "national" is because that's the last value you assigned to it earlier when you iterated through the list:

```
foreach($csv_array as $key => $value) {
    if ($key == 0) {
        continue;
    }
    $line = explode(',', $value);
```

I'm sure it's possible with less redesign, but like I said, I was a little unclear with what each line of code was intended to do. In particular, if you had error reporting on, then you would have noticed a lot of:

> Notice:  Undefined offset: 1 in

```
if (array_key_exists($line[1], $tables)) {
    $tables[$line[1]][] = $line;
} else {
    $tables[$line[1]] = [$line];
}
```

As an aside, this would probably be a lot easier if you had more control over generating that CSV output, from say a relational database, then you could use GROUP BY clauses and get better output formatted to your particular need.

At any rate, in order to solve this, I opted for a full redesign firstly by populating a parsed array with all CSV values.

```
<?php
// no need for extra \n's when inside quoted string
$csv = "League,Team,Date,Opponent,Result
american,MIN,May 3,UTA,W
american,MIN,May 4,SEA,L
american,SAC,May 3,DAL,L
american,SAC,May 4,TOR,W
national,NYN,May 5,BAL,L
national,NYN,May 7,MIA,W
national,DET,May 6,DEN,L
national,DET,May 7,POR,L";

$csv_array = explode("\n", $csv);

$headers = explode(",", $csv_array[0]);

// iterate through all lines of CSV, skipping first header line
for($i=1;$i<count($csv_array);$i++) {

  $line = explode(",", $csv_array[$i]);

  // iterate through all headers and assign corresponding line value
  foreach ($headers as $index => $header){
    $parsed_array[$i][$header] = $line[$index];
  }

}
```

This will give you a tidy associative array that looks like this:

```
Array
(
    [1] => Array
        (
            [League] => american
            [Team] => MIN
            [Date] => May 3
            [Opponent] => UTA
            [Result] => W
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [League] => american
            [Team] => MIN
            [Date] => May 4
            [Opponent] => SEA
            [Result] => L
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [League] => american
            [Team] => SAC
            [Date] => May 3
            [Opponent] => DAL
            [Result] => L
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [League] => american
            [Team] => SAC
            [Date] => May 4
            [Opponent] => TOR
            [Result] => W
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [League] => national
            [Team] => NYN
            [Date] => May 5
            [Opponent] => BAL
            [Result] => L
        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [League] => national
            [Team] => NYN
            [Date] => May 7
            [Opponent] => MIA
            [Result] => W
        )

    [7] => Array
        (
            [League] => national
            [Team] => DET
            [Date] => May 6
            [Opponent] => DEN
            [Result] => L
        )

    [8] => Array
        (
            [League] => national
            [Team] => DET
            [Date] => May 7
            [Opponent] => POR
            [Result] => L
        )

)
```

Now it's a fairly straightforward process to generating your custom divs and tables from this data:

```
// create divs and tables
foreach ($parsed_array as $i => $game) {

  // since we're interested in pairs, then create new div every other one
  // if odd, then open div/table
  if ($i % 2 !== 0){
    echo "
      <div class='$game[League]'>
        <table>
          <tr>
            <th>$game[Team]</th>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th>Date</th><th>Opponent</th><th>Result</th>
          </tr>
    ";
  }

  // print data
  echo "
          <tr><td>$game[Date]</td><td>$game[Opponent]</td><td>$game[Result]</td></tr>
  ";

  // if even, then close div/table
  if ($i % 2 === 0){
    echo "
        </table>
      </div>
    ";
  }

}
```

This will generate the html as provided in your question with the correct Leagues as div class names:

```html
<div class='american'>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <th>MIN</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>Date</th><th>Opponent</th><th>Result</th>
    </tr>

    <tr><td>May 3</td><td>UTA</td><td>W</td></tr>

    <tr><td>May 4</td><td>SEA</td><td>L</td></tr>

  </table>
</div>

<div class='american'>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <th>SAC</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>Date</th><th>Opponent</th><th>Result</th>
    </tr>

    <tr><td>May 3</td><td>DAL</td><td>L</td></tr>

    <tr><td>May 4</td><td>TOR</td><td>W</td></tr>

  </table>
</div>

<div class='national'>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <th>NYN</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>Date</th><th>Opponent</th><th>Result</th>
    </tr>

    <tr><td>May 5</td><td>BAL</td><td>L</td></tr>

    <tr><td>May 7</td><td>MIA</td><td>W</td></tr>

  </table>
</div>

<div class='national'>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <th>DET</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>Date</th><th>Opponent</th><th>Result</th>
    </tr>

    <tr><td>May 6</td><td>DEN</td><td>L</td></tr>

    <tr><td>May 7</td><td>POR</td><td>L</td></tr>

  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the clear answer, Jeff. My data is actually `$csv = file_get_contents('assets/schedules.csv');` Those errors only came up when I put in some dummy data. Sorry about that. However, that array_key_exists code was dividing the tables into their respective teams, which is necessary because the data will change, so it's not pairs of lines but rather unique team names that it should be looking for. Also, I had to put a comma after each value in the last column (Result) in order for the data to show up and prevent an undefined index error on the line that's printing the data. Any idea why?

Comment: @Beau you said "I had to put a comma after each value", but do you mean newline `\n`?

Comment: @Beau I guess I'm just blind because I really don't see the comma you're talking about in your posted question... Are you talking about in the data `american,MIN,May 3,UTA,W\n` or somewhere in the code?

Comment: @Beau well that doesn't make sense to me at all lol! Are you sure you copy/pasted the 1st and 3rd block exactly?

Comment: Yes, but that's okay, I can work on it, and at least I have a workaround. Any idea how to separate each div/table by unique team, as opposed to by pairs? I assume the array_key_exists code block from the original needs to be moved. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: @Beau sure, but you'll have to edit your question to include more realistic data that illustrates the problem.

Comment: I changed the data so that there is an inconsistent number of games per team. This means that div/table cannot be opened and closed with odd/even but rather by unique team names. In the original code, this was accomplished with `if (array_key_exists($line[1], $tables)) {` I assume that in your new code, a similar statement will now go immediately after `foreach ($parsed_array as $i => $game) {` and a new foreach will replace `if ($i % 2 === 0){` P.S. Can you delete your first two comments, and I'll do the same, as the last column issue doesn't seem to be universal.